# Calculate probability and its accuracy from results of experiments

Tags: probability

You have a machine that tells you which of two items weights more than the other. You insert one object in slot 1 and the other in slot 2, press a button and then the machine tells you either "Item in slot 1 is heavier than that in slot 2" or reverse. But the machine sometimes lies. It works this way:

- The machine does exactly remember all pairs it ever has compared in the past. Whenever it has to compare a pair that it did already compare in the past, it recalls the result from it's memory and gives it out. If you insert the same pair but swap the slots 1 and 2 then the machine will remember that pair too and will give the adjusted answer.
- If a pair is new:

  - With a probability of `p` (which is unknown to you):
    Place the items on a scale, measure which one is heavier than the other and then tell this result truthfully (and store it in the memory).
  - Otherwise:
    Do not weigh the objects. With a probability of 0.5 tell that the object in slot 1 is heavier than that in slot 2, otherwise tell the opposite. Store this answer in memory.

You are not really interested in the weights of the objects. You want to get knowledge of `p`.

Except this machine you have no other possibility to find out which of two objects is the heavier one.

You have a set of as much of different objects as you need, and you know that among them is no pair of two objects with the same weight. The difference of weights is always big enough to be correctly detected when the objects are placed on the scale.

But you have to pay for each comparison and can afford just `n` comparisons, but you want to determine p as exactly as possible.

**This are the issues I am dealing with:**

- What is the best strategy of selecting objects for being compared by the machine?
- How do you calculate p and its standard deviation (or a similar measurement for p's accuracy) from the results?

**What I did so far:**

If you use 3 objects (A, B, C) you can build 3 pairs (AB, AC, BC).
For each pair you can get two possible answers, which results in 8 possible combinations:

1. A < B, B < C, A < C (which gives the consistent order A < B < C)
2. A < B, B < C, A > C (This is inconsistent. The machine did lie at least once)
3. A < B, B > C, A < C (consistent: A < C < B)
4. A < B, B > C, A > C (consistent: C < A < B)
5. A > B, B < C, A < C (consistent: B < A < C)
6. A > B, B < C, A > C (consistent: B < C < A)
7. A > B, B > C, A < C (inconsistent)
8. A > B, B > C, A > C (consistent: C < B < A)

So, if `p` is 1 then the cases 2 and 7 never will happen. The other six cases are expected to appear with equal frequency.
If `p` is 0 then all eight cases appear with the same frequency which means that the inconsistent cases 2 and 7 together make 1/4 of all cases.

When `r` is the ratio of number of inconsistent triples divided by the number of all triples, then

p = √(1 - 4*r)

(I found this formula by numeric experiments in Excel. I have no idea how to derive it from the given problem.)

If you take four objects and build all possible pairs, then you can build four of those triples, but they are not independent. Each two triples have one pair in common which makes them not independent. So my approach is to build lots of triples and never use the same pair in more than one triple. If you take six objects (A, B, C, D, E, F) you can build four independent triples from them (like ABF, ACE, BCD and DEF). But although in this example you have all pairs to build even more triples (like ABC, CDE and so on) you should not use this triples for your calculation because those additional triples are highly dependent on the first four triples and they won't give you more information than you already have. You just will calculate a wrong accuracy.

Under this circumstances you have the same costs if you take three objects, build all three possible pairs from them which gives you one triple, and then you count this triple either as consistent or inconsistent. Then you take three new objects and repeat this process.

If you do so you can calculate p from the formula above, but I have no idea how to calculate p's standard deviation.

**This are my questions to you:**

- Do you have a better strategy to determine p?
- Is the formula p = √(1 - 4*r) correct?
  If yes: why?
  If no: What is the correct formula?
- How do you calculate p's accuracy (standard deviation)?

**Additional notes (not part of the problem):**

The original problem comes from a computer program that I am writing just now. Users are comparing two short texts (each text is just one or two short sentences) and have to click on the one that they like better, then they get the next pair. One user never has to compare the same pair of texts more then once, but each text can appear to the same user again and again, but each time combined with an other text.

The final goal is to calculate a global ranking of the texts (there are about 5000 different texts). But I found out that there are users who produce more consistent individual rankings than others. Some users don't really compare. The just click on any of the texts to get a new pair to read. I want to find a measure that tells me which users are doing their job carefully and who's click can be ignored because they are just random.

Answer (score 5):

With probability $p$ we make a consistent decision for certain. With probability $1-p$ we make a consistent decision with probability 0.75. So this implies $P($consistent$)=p+0.75(1-p)=\frac{3+p}{4}.$

Now we present the 3 pairs of a triple to a decision maker and repeat $n$ times. We let $x_i=1$ for a consistent response and $x_i=0$ for an inconsistent response. We now derive the maximum likelihood estimator of $p$. The likelihood function is
$$ \prod p(x_i)=\left(\frac{3+p} {4} \right)^{\sum x_i} \left( 1-\frac{3+p}{4} \right)^{n-\sum x_i}$$ 
Maximize this over $p$ by taking the ln() of both sides, taking the derivative w.r.t. $p$ and set $=0.$
$$\frac{\sum x_i} {3+p}=\frac{n-\sum x_i}{1-p}   $$

Solving for $p$ we obtain $ \hat p= 4 \bar x- 3$ where $\bar x = \sum x_i/n$ is the proportion of consistent responses. Or if we use the proportion of inconsistent responses  $r=1-\bar x$ then $\hat p=1-4r.$